# how to set a constraint that sets null on only one of the fields in the composite foreign key when the parent record is deleted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have 2 postgres tables.

table one:
|id|user_id|master_team_id|role_id

table two:
|uuid|user_id|master_team_id|number

- master_team_id in table two can be null.
- user_id and master_id foreign key references the user_id and
  master_team_id in table one.
- in order for master_team_id in table two to not be null, the user_id
  and master_team_id combo must exist in table one.

how do i add a constraint that sets null on only master_team_id in the composite key(user_id, master_team_id) in table two when the referenced row in table one is deleted?

Comment: Show your table definitions. If the constraints are just per field then you would just use `on delete set null` for the field in question.

Comment: i just need to set null to one of the fields though. the constraints are on 2 fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that yet.

What a coincidence.  The ability to do that was [committed yesterday](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=d6f96ed94e73052f99a2e545ed17a8b2fdc1fb8a), and (if all goes according to plan) will be included in v15, which is not due out for nearly a year.

You can use a trigger, which would look like this:

```
create table p (c1 int, c2 int, unique  (c1,c2));
create table c (c1 int, c2 int, r double precision);
alter table c add constraint fk99999 foreign key (c1,c2) references p (c1,c2);
create function update_c() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
  update c set c2=null where c1=old.c1 and c2=old.c2;
  return old;
END; $$;
create trigger sdjflsfd before delete ON p for each row execute function update_c();
```

Comment: Anyway I can achieve this with a trigger?

Comment: I think so.  A BEFORE DELETE trigger on the parent that updates the child should work, with a regular (on delete no action) FK constraint to catch race conditions.

Comment: can you give an example on writing such trigger please?

Answer (score 1):

in the FK constraint specify **ON DELETE SET NULL**

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php

**Side Note:** I would suggest using adding a new column to table two called "TableOneID" that way you can know if the matching record exists or not.

Comment: i just need to set null to one of the columns though not both. how do i specify which column? the constraints are on 2 columns though.